# Appending rows to existing gridview without loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, gridview

I have a function in Javascript which appends new rows to existing GridView.

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var customers = xml.find("ResultTable");
    $("[id$=grd] .loader").remove();
    customers.each(function () {
        var customer = $(this);
        var row = $("[id$=grd] tr").eq(1).clone(true);
        $(".groupname", row).html(customer.find("GroupName").text());
        $(".fullfundname", row).html(customer.find("FullFundName").text());
        $(".datafieldname", row).html(customer.find("DataFieldName").text());
        $(".comparisonresult", row).html(customer.find("ComparisonResult").text());

        $("[id$=grd]").append(row);
    });

}
```

This works as intended but it is slow. Each time 1000 records will be appended to the existing grid when this function is called.

Any pointers to improve the performance, like can we assign the entire xml in single shot. Note, my column names are fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to give you solution but i don't have the data for test. Hope this work.

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function (s) {
    return s ?
        this.before(s).remove() :
        jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};

function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var customers = xml.find("ResultTable");
    $("[id$=grd] .loader").remove();
    var template = $("[id$=grd] tr").eq(1).clone(true);
    template.find(".groupname").text("@@GROUPNAME");
    template.find(".fullfundname").text("@@FULLFUNDNAME");
    template.find(".datafieldname").text("@@DATAFIELDNAME");
    template.find(".comparisonresult").text("@@COMPARISONRESULT");
    template = template.outerHTML();
    let newRows = "";
    customers.each(function () {
        var customer = $(this);
        let row = template;
        row = row.replace("@@GROUPNAME", customer.find("GroupName").text());
           .replace("@@FULLFUNDNAME", customer.find("FullFundName").text());
           .replace("@@DATAFIELDNAME", customer.find("DataFieldName").text());
           .replace("@@COMPARISONRESULT", customer.find("ComparisonResult").text());
        newRows += row;
    });
    $("[id$=grd]").html($("[id$=grd]").html() + newRows);
}
```

Comment: Its not replacing the content, all 1000 records are full of `"@@GROUPNAME", "@@FULLFUNDNAME"", "@@DATAFIELDNAME" & "@@COMPARISONRESULT"`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. It would be great if you can explain what you have done.

Comment: i forgot to set back the value to row variable. :(
str.replace not automatic change variable value so we need to set it manual.

Comment: I understood that part. Could you please explain the entire approach. Mainly this part `jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function (s) {
    return s ?
        this.before(s).remove() :
        jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};`

Comment: outerHTML for get entire code from <tr> if we using html() it just give us html inside <tr>This</tr>. We need entire code for append html to table. Why i'm using template html instead of object. Replace is not heavy if we compare with find object using jquery. So we using jquery find just to prepare the template and we process using replace to input the data. Put object to table is a heavy task too for large data. so we put the data all at once in the end of process.

Comment: If your problem solved, can you please accept the solution? So this question mark as solved. :)